# Segmentation fault while cleaning up program

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm very new to C, and I've been going through Zed Shaw's "Learn C the Hard Way". I have experience in other languages, but mostly languages that handle their own memory management and so I'm new to some of this. I built the game described in [this lesson.](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html) and extended it slightly so I could define the game mechanics in one class and build the maps in another class. I am trying to build functions to handle the memory management and free all of the heap memory allocated by the program, but my program causes a segmentation fault while cleaning up.

I have defined a room object, based on an object super class, like this:

```
struct Room {
    Object proto;

    Monster *bad_guy;

    struct Room *north;
    struct Room *south;
    struct Room *east;
    struct Room *west;
};

typedef struct Room Room;

Object RoomProto;
```

I have this method called when the map is destroyed. The program causes a segmentation fault, according to valgrind, on the line destroying room->north. My thought behind this was that I'd check to see if the room existed and then destroy it if it did, that way I could go through all of the map and delete each room but not try to free any NULL pointers.

```
void Room_destroy(void *self)
{
    Room *room = self;


    if(room){
        if(room->north){
            room->north->_(destroy)(room->north);
        }
        if(room->south){
            room->south->_(destroy)(room->south);
        }
        if(room->west){
            room->west->_(destroy)(room->west);
        }
        if(room->east){
            room->east->_(destroy)(room->east);
        }
        if(room->bad_guy){
            room->bad_guy->_(destroy)(room->bad_guy);
        }
        room->_(destroy)(room);
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve the problem myself in a couple of ways, like first assigning pointers to null, like:
    Room *n = NULL;
    n = room->north;
and then checked n instead of just room->north. I know this is a common error and so I feel like I may just be missing some critical point about pointers, no pun intended.

Comment: Also, I have defined the macros: 
'#define NEW(T, N) Object_new(sizeof(T), T##Proto, N)'
'#define _(N) proto.N' 
in the object header in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: I've read your link and... well... if you want to learn this, go ahead, but that's so twisted that's it's almost incomprehensible. If you want objects, learn C++. Don't take C and twist it's arm until it somehow does objects in a freaky fashion. Use the right tool for the job. C is great. But please don't do OOP in C if you have C++ available.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm interested in starting to learn C for a Systems course I'm going to be taking in the Fall. If it's not worth my time to learn OOP in C, I won't, but I wasn't aware that this was such a bastardization of objects that it wasn't worth my time and I'm open to whatever insight you have.

Comment: `C` has no OOP features. You can simulate OOP the same way you can simulate a hammer by using a screwdriver's grip to drive in in nails. It's not that it's impossible, just not very convenient and looks pretty idiotic. Personal opinion: good C code free of errors is worth it's weight in gold (ok, probably more), but making it complicated by simulating features the language does not have is error prone and hard to understand. The exact opposite of what I want from software close to the core. Concentrate on the strong sides of each tool you use.

Comment: @nvoigt Okay thanks! I won't waste my time trying to emulate objects in C then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, So it seems that the link you provided is implementing OOP in C. That's bad.
If you are trying to learn C then it will be better to try to understand the basics first. This will only confuse you.

Now comes to your code. I tried to understand and here seems to be the problem. You are doing

```
if(room->north){
     room->north->_(destroy)(room->north);
}
...
```

You are calling the destroy function of the same object which you are passing as a parameter. So you are in the memory which you want to free. If you want to do like this then make it

```
if(room->north){
     room->_(destroy)(room->north);
}
...
```

This , I presume, will not cause any segmentation fault.

And just a small advice. don't mix-up the OOP and C. Otherwise, you will keep facing such kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks. This totally makes sense and also is super helpful in elucidating why OOP in C is bad/hard. I'll find another book to learn the language!

Answer (score 1):

What does this line even do? Is that standard C?

```
if(room->north){
        room->north->_(destroy)(room->north);
    }
```

This is the standard way of memory management:

```
if(pointer != NULL)
{
   free(pointer);
   pointer = NULL;
}
```

Replace `pointer` with any pointer you have, for example `room->north` and you are good. Don't forget to set all your pointers to either a piece of allocated memory or NULL from the start.

Comment: From the link there is `#define _(N) proto.N` so this looks like calling a function pointer. Still a non-obvious way to do things and not something I'd suggest doing to learn C.

Comment: just to add - `if(pointer != NULL)` is redundant. free() can take care of `NULL` ie. 'no action occurs' (C standard 7.20.3.2)